# Use UrlResolver for component relative URLs

Tags: angular

I want to use the UrlResolver to use component relative URLs in my template.

I've already implemented the UrlResolver in my code as described here: http://dfbaskin.com/posts/angular2-url-resolver-for-component-assets/

But every time the browser console just shows the error "No provider for UrlResolver!".

I'm totally new to Angular. Any idea how to fix this issue?

btw: I'm using SystemJS.

My component.ts:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {UrlResolver} from "@angular/compiler";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "my-template.html"
})

export class PageNotFoundComponent {
    constructor(private urlResolver: UrlResolver) {
    }

    public resolvePath(path) {
        return this.urlResolver.resolve(module.id, path);
    }
}
```

In my template (my-template.html) I have the following HTML:

```
<img [src]="resolvePath('some-resource.png')"/>
```

Comment: It would help the non-psychic among us to show the line(s) of code which produce this error...

Comment: I've added an example to my question.

Comment: which version of angular2 u r using?

Comment: I'm using the final release.

Answer (score 1):

To answer directly to your question, you should add `providers: [UrlResolver]` to your @Component.

**Like this:**

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "my-template.html",
    providers: [UrlResolver]
})
```

But that for me didn't give the solution to the main issue - how to get relative path to a resource.
Because then it started to complain about "No provider for Token Application Packages Root URL!".

Maybe you will be able to push further at least.

Comment: Did you able to find solution for "No provider for Token Application Packages Root URL!" issue, I am breaking my head to fix this issue :(